# File Upload does not work inside a Grid View and Ajax Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I want to upload a file inside a grid view and Ajax update panel. However, I think the file Upload tool can not post back inside an Ajax update panel.

I have used the trigger method, but it did not work! Can any body help me?

**Code Behind:**

```
if (((FileUpload)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload).HasFile)
{
    /////My stuffs
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
   DataKeyNames="ID,ArticleID,UserName" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
   GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 100%;">
               ....//Other Stuffs
            </table>
            <%-- </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
            </div>
            </article>
            </div>
            </section>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="FileUpload1" />
</Triggers>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like what u wrote the code it won't work Just try this

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Gridview1" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: Thank you, It works fine. However the Update progress Ajax tool can not work now! (I was showing the loading time) Is there any way that we make both File upload and Update progress worke at the same time?